# use jquery function in a highcharts

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, highcharts

If I have some function `myfunc` in a **js** file, how can I call this function from a php file to use it in `highcharts point.click event` like

```
point:{
       events:{
          click : myfunc()
         }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the function name without the brackets:

```
point: {
    events: {
        click: myfunc
    }
}
```

or wrap the execution call in a new anonymous function, allowing you to pass it some parameters:

```
point: {
    events: {
        click: new function(e) {
            myfunc(e, maybeSomethingElse);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried somehitng like:

```
point:{
       events:{
          click : function(){
             <?php yourfunction() ?>
          }
       }
}
```